# django manage.py throwing value error

Tags: python, django

Here is the stack trace i get when i run any manage.py commands

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/krishna/Documents/irrigationwebserver/webserver/irrigationservice/models.py", line 61, in <module>
    class IrrigationSession(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 189, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1783, in contribute_to_class
    super(ForeignObject, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, virtual_only=virtual_only)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 305, in contribute_to_class
    'app_label': cls._meta.app_label.lower()
ValueError: incomplete format
```

Here is the code in models.py and settings.py, those are the only places where I modified the django app.

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from model_utils.fields import StatusField, MonitorField
from model_utils import Choices, FieldTracker
from jsonfield import JSONField
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class LastRequestStorable(models.Model):
    last_service_request = JSONField()
    req_tracker = FieldTracker()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MapPointable(models.Model):
    loc_latitude = models.FloatField()
    loca_longtitude = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class FarmStateble(models.Model):
    STATES = Choices((0, 'SLEEPING', _('Sleeping')), (1, 'SENSING', _('Sensing')), (2, 'WATERING', _('Watering')))
    state = StatusField(choices_name = 'STATES')
    state_tracker = FieldTracker(fields=['state'])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Farmer(FarmStateble, MapPointable, LastRequestStorable, AbstractUser):
    last_irrigation_cycle = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null = True, blank=True)


class MoistureProfileDict(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MoistureKVPair(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(MoistureProfileDict)
    sector_key = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sector_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=3, default=0)


class BotanicData(models.Model):
    soil_choices = Choices('LOAM', 'SILT', 'CLAY', 'SAND')
    soil_type = models.CharField(choices= soil_choices, blank=True, max_length=20)
    seed_choices = Choices('TOMATOE', 'POTATOE', 'CARROT', 'STRAWBERRY', 'CHICKEN')
    seed = models.CharField(choices=seed_choices, blank = True, max_length=15)
    root_depth = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    field_capacity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=3, default=0)
    perm_wilt_point = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=3, default=0)
    max_depl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=3, default=0)


class Analytics(models.Model):
    power_used = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    water_used = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    water_saved = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=0)


class IrrigationSession(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    botany = models.OneToOneField(BotanicData)
    analytics = models.OneToOneField(Analytics)
    sector1_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)")
    sector2_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)")
    sector3_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)")
```

settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=%m-!gjz88m15lo^buqxuhqv7pv0ih_9)x+v#_dxub#ye&jbry'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'irrigationservice',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'irrigationservice.Farmer'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'webserver.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'webserver.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've tried to google the error or search stack overflow for some answers but I can't see what I did wrong.

EDIT 1:
After taking suggestions on changing the related name to be different for each one I've changed them to sess_1 sess_2 and sess_3 respectivly. but I now get this error which I was trying to avoid.

```
python manage.py makemigrations                                                            ✗ krish/modelsdefintion ☁
```

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

```
ERRORS:
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' clashes with reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' clashes with reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
```

EDIT 2: using %(class)s as related name

change in models.py

```
    sector1_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)s")
sector2_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)s")
sector3_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)s")
```

ERRORS:
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.

```
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof' clashes with reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof' clashes with reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' clashes with reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' clashes with reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' clashes with reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector1_moist_prof'.
irrigationservice.IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' clashes with reverse query name for 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IrrigationSession.sector3_moist_prof' or 'IrrigationSession.sector2_moist_prof'.
```

Comment: what do you try to do with `python manage.py`?

Comment: @pythad runserver, migrate, shell, all the same error

Comment: Your question has now changed into another question; this error is different from your original error.

Comment: I think the new error is pretty clear; it even gives you a hint what to do.

Comment: Can you please copy-paste your updated code? The `%(class)s` related name won't work (since that's identical for these fields), which suggests there's something else going on. Perhaps another typo, perhaps your migration file is now causing problems. If you're starting from scratch or you can afford it, clear/remove your database and migration file.

Comment: No, what I meant was, please show the model you used for your EDIT 1. This should have been the correct edit, but the traceback shows you must have made a mistake editing in sess_1 sess_2 and sess_3 for the related names. I suggest you try to add those again, show the edited code and the relevant error (the latter should be the same as in EDIT 1).

Comment: @Evert your right, I must have made a silly mistake, it worked, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can sugest you try to rewrite code:

```
sector1_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)")
sector2_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)")
sector3_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="%(class)")
```

You are declared three one to one relations but give them all one reverse name, which is not definitely - if you will try to do reverse - django orm will not know what exacly relation to use

Try:

```
sector1_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="sess_1")
sector2_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="sess_2")
sector3_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, related_name="sess_3")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an 's' in the formatter for related_name: `%(class)s`.

Use

```
sector1_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, \
related_name="%(class)s")
```

instead of

```
sector1_moist_prof = models.OneToOneField(MoistureProfileDict, \
related_name="%(class)")
```

(Ditto for the other fields.)

Comment: Updated the question, this didn't do it :(

Comment: Instead of changing the related_name to `sess_1`, `sess_2`: do you get the same, *original* error you had when chaing `%(class)` to `%(class)s`? Because I think this solves your original issue, and you just stumbled upon another error.

Comment: yes I still got the same error in the format of "HINT: add or change the related_name argument to the definition of sector3_moist_prof... Which I assume is the same error when using sess1 and sess2

Comment: No, that means you got a *different* error than the error in your original question. I.e., both explicitly specifying a name like "sess_1" or using "%(class)s" solved your original error, but now you've run into a different (related) issue. Your original problem has been solved (essentially an oversight), and you should ask a new question regarding this error; in particular since all three answers here relate to your original problem, and now have little to nothing to do with your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the traceback I can say that the problem is connected with `related_name`s.
I think you have to write `%(class)s` instead of `%(class)` in them